# Recursion to dynamic function

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion, dynamic, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to make dynamic function of recursive function and I'm a little bit stuck.

Recursion:

```
static int F(int m, int n)
    {
        if(n == 0)
            return m;

        if (m == 0 && n > 0)
            return n;

        else
            return Math.Min((1 + F(m - 1, n)), Math.Min((1 + F(m, n - 1)), (D(m-1, n-1) + F(m - 1, n - 1))));
    }

    static int D(int i, int j)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("i:{0} | j:{1}", i, j);
        if (x[i] == y[j])
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Dynamic(all I have so far):

```
static int F2(int m, int n)
    {
        if (n == 0)
        {
            return m;
        }
        if(m==0 && n > 0)
        {
            return n;
        }
        else
        {
            //Math.Min((1 + F(m - 1, n)), Math.Min((1 + F(m, n - 1)), (D(m-1, n-1) + F(m - 1, n - 1))));
        }
    }
```

**And the question is can someone explain to me how do I convert this `Math.Min((1 + F(m - 1, n)), Math.Min((1 + F(m, n - 1)), (D(m-1, n-1) + F(m - 1, n - 1))));` code into dynamic? I'm kind of new with recursion.**

Comment: The main complexity of DP algorithms is figuring out how to define one cell in terms of others. You already did that. Beyond that it's going to look almost the same as any other DP algorithm. I'm really struggling to see which part of the conversion you'd struggle with - it's all very straight-forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the dynamic-programming approach you would use a 2-dimensional lookup table, that you fill in such a way that you always have all data that you need available.

Since you recursion for `m` and `n` depends on `F(m - 1, n)`, `F(m, n - 1)` and `F(m - 1, n - 1)`, all you need to do is make sure that those values are computed already when you start computing `F(m, n)`. For example:

```
static int F2(int M, int N) {
    var F = new int[M + 1, N + 1];

    for (var m = 0; m <= M; m++) {
        for (var n = 0; n <= N; n++) {
            if (n == 0) {
                F[m, n] = m;
                continue;
            }
            if (m == 0 && n > 0) {
                F[m, n] = n;
                continue;
            }
            F[m, n] = Math.Min((1 + F[m - 1, n]), Math.Min((1 + F[m, n - 1]), (D(m-1, n-1) + F[m - 1, n - 1])));
        }
    }

    return F[M, N];
}
```

I chose the names so that it is easiest to see how it maps to the recursive approach.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's really helpful. :) I've tried your code and I'm getting an error.

Comment: @David, My bad, I changed < to <= in the loops

Comment: It works now. But I'm not sure why I'm getting the wrong answer.

Comment: You sould delete those "break;" statements, because they give the wrong answer :)

Comment: Both `break` statements should be `continue` instead - you still need to set `F` for the rest of the values of `n`.

Comment: Thanks @Dukeling, fixed those